# Is it possible to use different size (width) select box with uniform (jquery plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, width, uniform

I want to use multiple select box with multiple width with uniform . Problem is when I do

```
$('#small').uniform({selectClass:'smallSelect'});

$('#big').uniform({selectClass:'bigSelect'});

<select id="small">
<option>test</option>
</select>

<select id="big">
<option>test2</option>
</select>
```

Only the first one gets applied i.e bigSelect gets ignored .

Comment: can u provide class details for 'smallSelect' and 'bigSelect'

Comment: If that's your actual code.. you're missing a couple " marks

Comment: sorry for those small errors as this I typed here for question purpose .

Comment: @jaychapani the code of smallSelect and bigSelect is similar to 'selector' default class provided by uniform . I have simply replaced 'selector' with 'smallSelect' so there can not be problem .

Comment: @beginner I have updated the answer please check this

Comment: Please change the answer on this post. The marked answer is NOT correct. It's nice to do that for other people that will come on this post so they don't get the wrong information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the width of each select element by targeting the span that gets generated directly. The code creates a div wrapper with a unique id of uniform-yourid and child span element with the currently selected option. below is the css for your specified ids and you can add.

```
<style type="text/css">
#uniform-small span
{
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#uniform-big span
{
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Styles on the element are overriding the span styles, I had to remove the references to width in uniform.default.css

Answer (score 2):

@evanmcd, I was having the same problem as you and I found that if you set the `selectAutoWidth` to `false` it will take your css class into account.

```
$('select').uniform({selectAutoWidth: false});
```

and then in the css you define a style for `.selector`, which is the default cass for the div that holds the select itself.

Answer (score 0):

uniform.default.css is using image sprite.png for themes.

In this image width of various control is defined. So you can not change them as your requirement.

Comment: can you suggest any other library/plugin which is capable of doing that . thx .

Comment: Wrong answer, the images on the sprite accommodate for any size dropdown.  You need to change the size of the "div.selector span" that is generated.  That's it.

Comment: I agree, wrong answer.  Styling `.selector span` allows the width to be adjusted.